# How can I select all the text within a Windows Forms textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, selectall

I want to select all the text that is with in text box.

I've tried this using the code below:

```
textBoxResults.SelectionStart = 0;
textBoxResults.SelectionLength = textBoxResults.Text.Length;
```

Source: I got this code from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hk09zy8f(v=vs.100).aspx
but for some reason it doesn't seem to work - *meaning, no text gets selected*.

Comment: _(...)but it doesn't work.(...)_, what do you get in `selectedText` if you write `var selectedText = textBoxResults.SelectedText;`? Are you modifying the text property after the code above?

Comment: No, this is after programmatically populating the textbox. I just want to quickly highlight everything so I don't have to scroll through a gazillion lines of text.

Comment: How much text is in there?

Comment: A lot; too much to quickly drag through.

Comment: What **doesn't work**? Is the text only partially selected? Or not selected at all? You have to provide more details about your problem.

Comment: Nothing at all happens.

Comment: And the same exact comment could be made regarding this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034016/why-is-one-of-my-select-dropdowns-disappearing-once-content-is-loaded-below-it

Comment: It was answered below by Ehsan Ullah, so he understood it, and it's working now - in addition to SelectAll(), I also had to call Focus() after that. IOW, it was selected (theoretically, at least), but how would I know that. Seems like a strange implementation to me, but, as I said, the question has been answered/solved.

Comment: I had the same issue until I set the HideSelection property for textbox to false....

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use the built in method for this purpose.

```
textBoxResults.SelectAll();
textBoxResults.Focus(); //you need to call this to show selection if it doesn't has focus
```

Comment: That would seem sensible, but it doesn't work, either. I added textBoxResults.SelectAll();

Comment: i have tested it, it works eperfectly fine. Can you show how have you implemented it. it must be something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: It's very simple: I programmatically populate the textbox, then I have  a button with that code in it. I tried what I posted, which didn't work, and I tried the SelectAll(), which also doesn't work.

Comment: got your problem, call textBoxResults.Focus() after selectall call

Comment: @ClayShannon is your issue resolved? have you tried the updated code?

Comment: Or set the `HideSelection` property to `false`.

Comment: Okay, with the added .Focus() it works, thanks. Strange that the official way to do it from msdn led me down the garden path.

Comment: I always upvote every answer to one of my questions as soon as I see it - before I even read it.

Comment: I typed the following code in the "Enter" event of a Textbox. When i click into the Textbox, text is not selected:
`Textbox1.SelectAll();
Textbox1.Focus();`

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the following which might solve you problem:

```
textBoxResults.SelectAll();
```

This works well with multi-lined textbox.

Answer (score 2):

This method enables you to select all text within the control.

```
public void CopyAllMyText()
{
// Determine if any text is selected in the TextBox control. 
if(textBox1.SelectionLength == 0)
   // Select all text in the text box.
   textBox1.SelectAll();

// Copy the contents of the control to the Clipboard.
textBox1.Copy();
}
```

Check this link for more info. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectall.aspx

Comment: Why would I need to check for selectionlength? I want to select all with nothing selected prior to that.

Comment: You can remove if condition.